# Lodash partial with object path

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using lodash or arrow functions, what is the more elegant way to rewrite the `func` declaration in the following example ?

```
  function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }

  let foo = {};
  let func = function (v) { return multiply(v, _.get(foo, 'bar')) };
  foo.bar = 4;
  console.log(func(4)); //Result in 16

  let foo2 = {};
  let func2 = _.unary(_.partialRight(multiply, _.get(foo2, 'bar')));
  foo2.bar = 4;
  console.log(func2(4)); //Result in NaN

  let foo3 = {};
  let func3 = (v) => multiply(v, _.get(foo3, 'bar'));
  foo3.bar = 4;
  console.log(func3(4)); //Result in NaN
```

I tried with arrow function and partial but can't get it to work as you can see

Comment: you want to replace only `func` function?

Comment: Yep, the rest is here as an example. In my real world case, I need to instantiate multiple `func` like functions so I wanted to write it the best way. It's usually easy to shorten function calls with lodash but in that case, I don't see how

Comment: what about `_.multiply` ?

Comment: `multiply` was an example, sorry if this is misleading, in my case, it is a more complex function that I need to wrap

Comment: so i dont understand your question

Comment: I'm looking to rewrite this into a much nicer way : `function (v) { return multiply(v, _.get(foo, 'bar')) };`. Every other line of code are here to provide a working example

Comment: The third one is returning 16 for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your third option is working.](http://jsbin.com/jixakojoku/1/edit?js,console)

The second option is not working, because `_.get(foo2, 'bar')` get's immediately evaluated and puts `foo2.bar` in `partialRight` as a parameter, which is `undefined`, because the 4 get's assigned later.

Therefore `multiply` calculates `4 * undefined` which is `NaN`.

Improvements could be:

- [curry](https://lodash.com/docs/#curry) `multiply`
- make `func` [pure](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976#.qvvsxb67c)

For example:

```
  const multiply = _.curryRight(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  })

  let foo3 = {};
  foo3.bar = 4;
  let func3 = multiply(_.get(foo3, 'bar'));
  console.log(func3(4));
```

Comment: Indeed, the third option is working. I might have made a mistake while testing it.

However, even if I really do like currying functions, I don't find it elegant in this situation. It's overkilling the problem.

I think I'll give a go to the third option since it's the most readabble and clear implementation. Thanks